# Gradle + Android, want to overwrite /assets with custom folder in buildFlavor

Tags: android, gradle

In my current build scripts I have special /res/ and /assets folders that I copy over the working versions of the files at build time. In /assets/ is bundled data (sql and a text file) while in /res/values/ I have a connection.xml values file.

There are already duplicates of these files in the working directory, however at build time I want to use the ones from the /config/ folder of my project and copy them over the ones in the /res and /assets for the current build.

In my verbose logging I get a 
"com.android.ide.common.res2.DuplicateDataException" when it tries to copy the file.

Any idea's how to handle this? I can make the filename unique, but the key/value pairs inside it will not be? Would that solve the issue?

My Build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.0'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion "Google Inc.:Google APIs:18"
    buildToolsVersion "17"

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file("../../TioClient/keystore/android.keystore")
            storePassword "REDACTED"
            keyAlias "pge-android"
            keyPassword "lightmaker"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        dev {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
        tps {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
        production {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 15
    }

    dependencies {
       compile project(':TioClient'); 
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = []
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }
        tps {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = []
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res','config/tps/res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets', 'config/tps/assets']

        }
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
    }


}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can define assets at the buildtype level or product flavor level by including appropriate folders in your `src`.

Build type resources override flavor resources which override main resources.