# Android Proguard "Can't find referenced"

Tags: android, apk, proguard, signed

I want to generate a signed apk. But I reached the 64k methods limit so I searched for some solutions and one of them is to use proguard.
I edited my build.gradle like this:

```
 buildTypes {

        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

    }
```

When I then try to generate the signed apk I get a lot of warnings:

```
Warning:com.akexorcist.roundcornerprogressbar.TextRoundCornerProgressBar$2: can't find referenced method 'android.widget.TextView access$000(com.akexorcist.roundcornerprogressbar.TextRoundCornerProgressBar)' in program class com.akexorcist.roundcornerprogressbar.TextRoundCornerProgressBar
Warning:com.akexorcist.roundcornerprogressbar.TextRoundCornerProgressBar$2: can't find enclosing method 'void setTextProgressAlign()' in program class com.akexorcist.roundcornerprogressbar.TextRoundCornerProgressBar
Warning:com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.base.RealmBarLineScatterCandleBubbleDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmResults
Warning:com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.base.RealmBarLineScatterCandleBubbleDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmObject
Warning:com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.base.RealmBaseDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.Sort
Warning:com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.base.RealmBaseDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmResults
Warning:com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.base.RealmBaseDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.Sort
Warning:com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.base.RealmBaseDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmResults
Warning:com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.base.RealmBaseDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmObject
Warning:com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.base.RealmLineRadarDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmResults
Warning:com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.base.RealmLineRadarDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmObject
Warning:com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.base.RealmLineRadarDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.DynamicRealmObject
Warning:com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.base.RealmLineRadarDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmResults
Warning:com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.base.RealmLineRadarDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.DynamicRealmObject
Warning:com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.base.RealmLineRadarDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmObject
Warning:com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.base.RealmLineRadarDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.DynamicRealmObject
Warning:com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.base.RealmLineRadarDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmObject
Warning:com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.base.RealmLineRadarDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmResults
Warning:com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.base.RealmLineRadarDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmObject
Warning:com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.base.RealmLineScatterCandleRadarDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmResults
Warning:com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.base.RealmLineScatterCandleRadarDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmObject
Warning:com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.base.RealmUtils: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmResults
Warning:com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.base.RealmUtils: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmObject
Warning:com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.base.RealmUtils: can't find referenced class io.realm.DynamicRealmObject
Warning:com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.base.RealmUtils: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmResults
Warning:com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.base.RealmUtils: can't find referenced class io.realm.DynamicRealmObject
Warning:com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.base.RealmUtils: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmObject
Warning:com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.base.RealmUtils: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmResults
Warning:com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.base.RealmUtils: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmObject
Warning:com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.base.RealmUtils: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmResults
Warning:com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.base.RealmUtils: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmObject
Warning:com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmBarData: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmResults
Warning:com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmBarData: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmObject
Warning:com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmBarData: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmResults
Warning:com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmBarData: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmObject
Warning:com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmBarDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmResults
Warning:com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmBarDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmObject
Warning:com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmBarDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.DynamicRealmObject
Warning:com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmBarDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmList
Warning:com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmBarDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmResults
Warning:com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmBarDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmObject
Warning:com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmBarDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.DynamicRealmObject
Warning:com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmBarDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmList
Warning:com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmBarDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmResults
Warning:com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmBarDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmList
Warning:com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmBarDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmResults
Warning:com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmBarDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.DynamicRealmObject
Warning:com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmBarDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmList
Warning:com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmBarDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.DynamicRealmObject
Warning:com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmBarDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmObject
Warning:com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmBarDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmResults
Warning:com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmBarDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmList
Warning:com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmBarDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.DynamicRealmObject
Warning:com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmBarDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmResults
Warning:com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmBarDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmObject
Warning:com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmBubbleData: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmResults
Warning:com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmBubbleData: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmObject
Warning:com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmBubbleData: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmResults
Warning:com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmBubbleData: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmObject
Warning:com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmBubbleDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmResults
Warning:com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmBubbleDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmObject
Warning:com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmBubbleDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.DynamicRealmObject
Warning:com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmBubbleDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmResults
Warning:com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmBubbleDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.DynamicRealmObject
Warning:com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmBubbleDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmObject
Warning:com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmBubbleDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.DynamicRealmObject
Warning:com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmBubbleDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmObject
Warning:com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmBubbleDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmResults
Warning:com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmBubbleDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmObject
Warning:com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmCandleData: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmResults
Warning:com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmCandleData: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmObject
Warning:com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmCandleData: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmResults
Warning:com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmCandleData: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmObject
Warning:com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmCandleDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmResults
Warning:com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmCandleDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmObject
Warning:com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmCandleDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.DynamicRealmObject
Warning:com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmCandleDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmResults
Warning:com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmCandleDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.DynamicRealmObject
Warning:com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmCandleDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmObject
Warning:com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmCandleDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.DynamicRealmObject
Warning:com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmCandleDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmObject
Warning:com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmCandleDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmResults
Warning:com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmCandleDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmObject
Warning:com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmLineData: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmResults
Warning:com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmLineData: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmObject
Warning:com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmLineData: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmResults
Warning:com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmLineData: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmObject
Warning:com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmLineDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmResults
Warning:com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmLineDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmObject
Warning:com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmPieData: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmResults
Warning:com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmPieData: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmObject
Warning:com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmPieData: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmResults
Warning:com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmPieData: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmObject
Warning:com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmPieDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmResults
Warning:com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmPieDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmObject
Warning:com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmPieDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.DynamicRealmObject
Warning:com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmPieDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmResults
Warning:com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmPieDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.DynamicRealmObject
Warning:com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmPieDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmObject
Warning:com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmPieDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.DynamicRealmObject
Warning:com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmPieDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmObject
Warning:com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmPieDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmResults
Warning:com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmPieDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmObject
Warning:com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmRadarData: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmResults
Warning:com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmRadarData: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmObject
Warning:com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmRadarData: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmResults
Warning:com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmRadarData: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmObject
Warning:com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmRadarDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmResults
Warning:com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmRadarDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmObject
Warning:com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmScatterData: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmResults
Warning:com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmScatterData: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmObject
Warning:com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmScatterData: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmResults
Warning:com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmScatterData: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmObject
Warning:com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmScatterDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmResults
Warning:com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmScatterDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmObject
Warning:com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmScatterDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.DynamicRealmObject
Warning:com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmScatterDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmResults
Warning:com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmScatterDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.DynamicRealmObject
Warning:com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmScatterDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmObject
Warning:com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmScatterDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.DynamicRealmObject
Warning:com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmScatterDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmObject
Warning:com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmScatterDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmResults
Warning:com.github.mikephil.charting.data.realm.implementation.RealmScatterDataSet: can't find referenced class io.realm.RealmObject
Warning:there were 283 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
Warning:there were 2 unresolved references to program class members.
Warning:Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForFreeRelease'.
> java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
```

So the problem seem to be the repositories I implemented. I read that I have to configurate the proguard-rules.pro file but I never used this before and have no idea about the syntax.
How can I fix that?

**EDIT**
Dependencies:

```
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.bignerdranch.android:expandablerecyclerview:2.1.1'
    compile 'com.github.lzyzsd:circleprogress:1.1.0@aar'
    compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.2.3'
    compile 'net.qiujuer.genius:ui:1.5.2'
    compile 'com.akexorcist:RoundCornerProgressBar:2.0.3'
    compile 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'
    compile 'com.github.medyo:fancybuttons:1.8.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.github.sundeepk:compact-calendar-view:1.9.3'
```

Comment: Add the dependencies part of `build.gradle`.

Comment: @R.Zagórski I made an edit

Comment: buildTypes {
        release 
            debuggable false
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two problematic libraries:

[RoundCornerProgressBar](https://github.com/akexorcist/Android-RoundCornerProgressBar)

[MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart)

The first problem is with the class `com.akexorcist.roundcornerprogressbar.TextRoundCornerProgressBar`. There is a solution [here](https://github.com/akexorcist/Android-RoundCornerProgressBar/issues/43) that overcomes the problem, by adding to Proguard:

```
-dontwarn com.akexorcist.roundcornerprogressbar.TextRoundCornerProgressBar
```

The second one is simply solved by adding two statements to Proguard that the author of the library clearly describes [here](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/Proguard):

```
-keep class com.github.mikephil.charting.** { *; }
-dontwarn io.realm.**
```

Your Proguard file should contain those lines and the problems should disappear.

Comment: Thank you so much! All warnings dissappeared! I had never find that out without you!

Answer (score -1):

buildTypes {

```
    release {
        debuggable false
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }


    debug {
        debuggable true
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

Comment: why minifyenabled on false in release? I need to shrink my apk

Comment: Flag minifyEnabled stays for ProGuard, and it's turned off by default. So, in default setup both debug and release builds aren't using ProGuard, and parameter proguardFiles is effectively ignored  If U need proguard enable minifyEnabled true.

Comment: But that does not helping me make the warnings dissappear!

Comment: Use  multiDexEnabled true

Comment: and also include dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}

Comment: No i dont. Im using proguard.

Comment: Are using Eclipse with android sdk or android studio

Comment: buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
                                                 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

Comment: And also add this dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}

Comment: Refer this link https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html and scroll down to check.

Comment: I already marked the correct answer above that solved my problem. Multidex is not an option for me. thx