# Use an Android Library (AAR) as dependency for a Java (Jar) Project with Gradle

Tags: android, unit-testing, gradle, rx-android

The Java Jar `build.gradle` module:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    // rx
    compile "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.0.4"
    compile "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1"
}

sourceCompatibility = "1.8"
targetCompatibility = "1.8"
```

This Jar is supposed to be a library used as an utility library for unit testing android projects:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    // ...
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    // test
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile project(':test-utils')

    // ... other non-test dependencies here (including rx)
}
```

This include:

```
    testCompile project(':test-utils')
```

fails with:

> Error:Module 'my-android-app:test-utils:unspecified' depends on one or
>   more Android Libraries but is a jar

Which is because `RxAndroid` is an Android .aar library.

I need RxAndroid in my test utility module because one of the things the module provide is a junit `MethodRule` for setting up Rx Schedulers through the `@Rule` annotation and other custom annotations in `@Test` methods.

This is needed because RxAndroid AndroidScheduler use Android `Handler` / `Looper` class, which are part of the Android framework and are not available in unit tests. The Android Scheduler can be replaced using `RxAndroidPlugins`.

Which means I only need the JAR part of the RxAndroid AAR (`classes.jar` inside rxandroid artifact).

Is there a way to tell gradle I only need the Java part of the AAR as dependency?

I do not consider a solution manually extracting the `classes.jar` from the AAR and including it as a dependency. That's a workaround.

This Java test library is supposed to be shared among my projects and I'm currently copying the `MethodRule` class in every of my projects which is far from ideal.

Comment: refer to this link : http://stackoverflow.com/a/26228126/7111867 it may help u

Comment: thank you, but that's for handling local dependencies *as-if* they were standard artifacts. In other words it makes your libs/ directory act like a fake maven repository and thus allow you to include dependency in the standard compile 'group:name:version@type' fashion. What I need is get the dependency from jcenter (real maven repo) but only depend to the `classes.jar` inside it (aka = the java part)

Comment: try this one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34525498/7111867

i think you also wants something like this

Comment: that's really interesting, but, unless I'm completely off on how gradle works, removing stuff from the aar is not going to make it a non-android-library package or make the java project include the classes.jar file inside it. Thank you for your input anyway, very instructive.

Comment: anytime welcome :)

Comment: I really think the answer lies within [Gradle's "Transforming dependency artifacts on resolution" docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/artifact_transforms.html), and see how AGP does it: `com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.ExtractAarTransform`.
We need to find a path between these two attribute sets: "Incompatible because this .component declares **a component, with the library elements 'aar'** and the consumer needed **a component, preferably in the form of class files**". I had a quick go, but no luck so far.