# strings.xml conflict in Android Manifest

Tags: android, xml

I have this in Android Manifest:

```
<application
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    ...
</application>
```

and in `strings.xml`:

```
 <string name="app_name">My App Name</string>
```

Everything ok. Now, my problem is that I'm using an `aar` dependency whose `strings.xml` file contains an item named `app_name`, too.

```
 <string name="app_name">My Library Name</string>
```

And my project is using the second one instead.

How can I solve this conflict?

Comment: I think only solution is use different names

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29829883 If your aar file is one of your own projects, you could either exclude it, or (in my opinion better) rename all resources to have a prefix such as "lib_<uniquename>_"

Comment: you use different name of first one....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> A unique resource name for the element, which you can use to obtain a
>   reference to the View from your application.

For better way , Just use **Different String Name** .

Answer (score 1):

```
**Its very easy change key value app_name as per your way**

example

change strings.xml
<string name="app_name">My App Name</string> line like
<string name="my_app_name">My App Name</string>

Then in manifest file use
<application
    android:label="@string/my_app_name"
    ...
</application>
```